# IDAPython Export All Addresses Called by Specific Call

Tags: ida, idapython

The following call gets executed many times and jumps to many subroutines.

```
call    [rbp+var_s38]
```

What do I need to write in the breakline condition to export all the locations it jumps to?

```
import idautils
f = open('C:\\Users\\vmware\\Desktop\\locations.txt', 'a+')
f.write(str(some_idautils_function))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know idapython very well, but an idc solution would be:

```
auto f = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
fprintf(f, "%016X\n", get_qword(rbp+<actual offset that is var_s38>));
fclose(f);
```

I know that sometimes idapython will use the same function names as idc, so maybe try searching the docs for `get_qword`

Comment: Much appreciated. I'll give it a go in IDC.